Laraves Filament Railway Deploy 403 error
I am working with Laravel and Filament, and I deployed my project on Railway. The problem is that I get a 403 status when I try to log in; it redirects me to 403. I checked the Filament documentation and found this:
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/installation#allowing-users-to-access-a-panel
But when I implement it in my code, it throws an error:
"Method 'App\Models\User::canAccessPanel()' is not compatible with method 'Filament\Models\Contracts\FilamentUser::canAccessPanel()'."
Attached is an image of the error as well.
Thanks for the help!
I can access to /admin panel, just /admin/login panelvscode User.php error

Code and error-messages should be pasted into questions (and answers) as text. This makes them clear to read and able to found by searching. Please edit the question to past the method in a text-block, delimited by triple-back-ticks.

Here's an example where it looks like it was made to work.

You need to include "Filament/Panel" before the class:
use Filament\Panel;

Look at the example code they have given:
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Filament\Models\Contracts\FilamentUser;
use Filament\Panel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 
class User extends Authenticatable implements FilamentUser
{
    // ...
 
    public function canAccessPanel(Panel $panel): bool
    {
        return str_ends_with($this->email, '@yourdomain.com') && $this->hasVerifiedEmail();
    }
}

This method expects a Filament\Panel input which therefore needs to be used and returns a bool. So you need
use Filament\Panel;

Note that the error message did not complain about unknown Panel, so it's possible that you have another Panel class from another namespace, in which case you can do
use Filament\Panel FilamentPanel;

and then have FilamentPanel $panel in the method declaration.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Add This part in your User class
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/iVJSZa2j.png

Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors read [answer] and explain what your answer post contributes beyond already existing answer.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
